# Set the permalink to any domain in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is this possible to achieve without too much effort or a plugin? It's simply to instantly redirect to a site I've made in my portfolio if the post doesn't have any content.

Note that I don't want a script in the actual post to redirect since I only use Wordpress as the backend and fetch all the data to be used by a JavaScript backbone app.

EDIT : Added some extra info in a comment

Comment: Do you mean the permalink of a post? I should think a plugin could do this, why don't you wish to use one? Edit: actually, not sure what you mean at all - can you explain further what you want to do?

Comment: What's your question? What are you trying to accomplish? What have you already tried?

Comment: Ok, so lets say i have a post, i want to be able to set the permalink of that post to http://example.com even though my site is located at http://someotherdomain.com. I've tested a good amount of plugins, but found none that let me do this

Comment: I'm not sure about the others, but I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. You want to send the user to another website if you have the post? Why? Wouldn't it make more sense to send the user to your other site if you don't have a post that matches on the current site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No. You cannot set your Post Permalink to an external asset without directly editing the database.

**Long Answer:** First off, you need to understand the purpose of the Permalink. It isn't just an arbitrary link to *somewhere*. It's reserved specifically for storing where that specific post lives within the context of your Wordpress installation.

Your post doesn't live on example.com. It has its own ID, and Wordpress has a specific spot set aside for it where it can be seen on YOUR domain. Leave it as such.

Instead, what you should be doing is employing the tools Wordpress gives you to achieve what you want. A Plugin doesn't exist for what you want because - quite frankly - it's a fairly trivial task when approached CORRECTLY and doesn't warrant the use of an external resource.

### So what's the correct way?

Use a [Custom Field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). Name your Custom Field something like 'externalHref' and fill that in with your link to the website you want to point to in case there's no post content.

Then in whatever templates you're using to generate your posts, just check either for the existence of your Custom Field called 'externalHref' or check for the non-existence of Post Content. In either case, instead of generating a link using [The Permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) you can simply build a link that points to wherever you need.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might have been the case. And i suppose this is the best practice, still hate to have fields that i don't use, that's the only reason i wanted to use the permalink. Thanks again, love helpful answers